# SSRS: How to fix pie chart size

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 pie charts in a report.
In the Report Builder they look the same size. But in the Web Browser (view the report) actual size (diameter) of charts is different due to data labels.

[See the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnbcJ.png)

How can I fix pie chart size in the Report Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the position of the chart area and the plot position of the pie within the area by setting the `CustomPosition` and `CustomInnerPlotPosition` properties. Select the chart area first to see these properties.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alan. But does the Position property fix diagram scaling?

Comment: It helps! Thanks!